# Detect the left most point of black color from UIImagview in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, position, core-graphics

I am stuck to find the left most point/Frame/Position from detect the `UIImageView`. I tried to detect black color pixels from `UIImageView` as below:

```
-(void)Black_findcolor
{
    UIImage *image = imgview.image;//imgview from i want to detect the most black color pixels.

    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
    int myWidth = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
    int myHeight = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
    const UInt8 *pixels = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
    UInt8 blackThreshold = 10 ;
  //  UInt8 alphaThreshold = 100;
    int bytesPerPixel_ = 4;
    CGFloat Xvalue,Yvalue;
    int x = 0,y=0;
    for( x = 0; x < myWidth; x++)
    {
        for( y = 0; y < myHeight; y++)
        {
            int pixelStartIndex = (x + (y * myWidth)) * bytesPerPixel_;
            UInt8 alphaVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex];
            UInt8 redVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 1];
            UInt8 greenVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 2];
            UInt8 blueVal = pixels[pixelStartIndex + 3];

            if(redVal < blackThreshold || blueVal < blackThreshold || greenVal < blackThreshold || alphaVal < blackThreshold)
            {
                NSLog(@"x =%d, y = %d", x, y);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

From above i get the different x and y pixels value but i want to that as points. So i have to set the pin on that `UIImageView` of left most black color point .

```
imgPin1.center=CGPointMake(x, y);//i tried but didnt get succeed in it // imgpin1 is Global imageview.
```

So can any one give me idea or suggestion how to set the frame or position of left most black color pixel of imgpin1?

If any other info need then tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want your pin at the beginning of cards black stripe is it?

Comment: yes exactly...left and right most ..

Comment: Yes I am testing some variations. Will let you know in a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**
Please have a look into my edited answer

```
    //You need to get resized image from your imageView in case of sizeToFit etc.
    float oldWidth = yourImageView.image.size.width;
    float scaleFactor = yourImageView.frame.size.width / oldWidth;

    float newHeight = yourImageView.image.size.height * scaleFactor;
    float newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight));
    [yourImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    CGSize size = newImage.size;
    int width = size.width;
    int height = size.height;
    int xCoord = width, yCoord = height;
    UInt8 blackThreshold = 10;


    // raw data will be assigned into this array
    uint32_t *pixels = (uint32_t *) malloc(width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

    // clear the pixels so any transparency is preserved
    memset(pixels, 0, width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // create a context with RGBA pixels
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace,
                                                 kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    // fill in the pixels array
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), [yourImageView.image CGImage]);

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            uint8_t *rgbaPixel = (uint8_t *) &pixels[y * width + x];

            // convert to grayscale using recommended method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale
            uint32_t gray = 0.3 * rgbaPixel[1] + 0.59 * rgbaPixel[2] + 0.11 * rgbaPixel[3];

            if (gray < blackThreshold)
            {
                if (x<xCoord)
                {
                    xCoord = x;
                    yCoord = y;
                    NSLog(@"X:%d Y:%d",xCoord,yCoord);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    // we're done with the context and pixels
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(pixels);

    imgPin1.center=CGPointMake(xCoord, yCoord);
```

Note if you use your original image to iterate through all pixels and try to display your pin onto your `UIImageView` you will get the  `X` and `Y` coordinates of your pixel in image original size, which will not correspond to the actual coordinates of your `UIImage` presented in your `UIImageView`

Comment: thanks for answer ...but didn't detect any black color pixel on my UIImageview....can you help me for it ?

Comment: Sure. Let me just try this here in my xcode. What image you're using?

Comment: edited my question and there is i used that image.in that i want to black color strip as detection.

Comment: Please take a look in to my edited answer. Tested and working as you required.

Comment: thanks a lot for it ...can you tell me what is scater ?
other wise can you share whole project here ...that fine for me.

Comment: It was my `imageView` :) just replaced this bit of code in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54444/discussion-between-dhaval-bhadania-and-panayot-panayotov).